# Maven: How can I verify that all beans are created and initialized

Tags: java, spring, maven, javabeans

How can I verify that all beans are created and initialized?
I've noticed, that `maven clean install` is successful even if I have some failed beans

Comment: What has Maven to do with beans?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a test that tries to load the whole context with all the beans. You can look up about @SpringBootTest(considering you are using Spring)